# How can I initialize and increment an undefined value within a list in Python 3?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

What I have is a dictionary of words and I'm generating objects that contain
(1) Original word (e.g. cats)
(2) Alphabetized word (e.g. acst)
(3) Length of the word

Without knowing the length of the longest word, is it possible to create an array (or, in Python, a list) such that, as I scan through the dictionary, it will append an object with x chars into a list in array[x]?

For example, when I encounter the word "a", it will append the generated object to the list at array[1]. Next, for aardvark, if will append the generated object to the list at array[8], etc.

I thought about creating an array of size 1 and then adding on to it, but I'm not sure how it would work.

Foe example: for the first word, a, it will append it to the list stored in array[1]. However, for next word, aardvark, how am I supposed to check/generate more spots in the list until it hits 8? If I append to array, I need give the append function an arg. But, I can't give it just any arg since I don't want to change previously entered values (e.g. 'a' in array[1]).

I'm trying to optimize my code for an assignment, so the alternative is going through the list a second time after I've determined the longest word. However, I think it would be better to do it as I alphabetize the words and create the objects such that I don't have to go through the lengthy dictionary twice.

Also, quick question about syntax: listOfStuff[x].append(y) will initialize/append to the list within listOfStuff at the value x with the value y, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the lengths as keys in a dict rather than as indexes in a list. This is really easy if you use a `defaultdict` from the collections module - your algorithm will look like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
results = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
   results[len(word)].append(word)
```

This ties in to your second question: `listOfStuff[x].append(y)` will append to a list that already exists at `listofStuff[x]`. It will *not* create a new one if that hasn't already been initialised to a (possibly empty) list. If `x` isn't a valid index to the list (eg, x=3 into a listOfStuff length 2), you'll get an IndexError. If it exists but there is something other than another list there, you will probably get an AttributeError.

Using a dict takes care of the first problem for you - assigning to a non-existent dict key is always valid. Using a `defaultdict` extends this idea to also *reading* from a non-existent key - it will insert a default value given by calling the function you give the defaultdict when you create it (in this case, we gave it `list`, so it calls it and gets an empty list) into the dict the first time you use it.

---

If you can't use collections for some reason, the next best way is still to use dicts - they have a method called `setdefault` that works similarly to defaultdicts. You can use it like this:

```
results = {}
for word in words:
     results.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)
```

as you can see, setdefault takes two arguments: a key and a default value. If the key already exists in the dict, setdefault just returns its current value as if you'd done `results[key]`. If that would be an error, however, it inserts the second argument into the dictionary at that key, and then returns it. This is a little bit clunkier to use than defaultdict, but when your default value is an empty list it is otherwise the same (defaultdict *is* better to use when your default is expensive to create, however, since it only calls the factory function as needed, but you need to precompute it to pass into setdefault).

---

It *is* technically possible to do this with nested lists, but it is ugly. You have to:

- Detect the case that the list isn't big enough
- Figure out how many more elements the list needs
- Grow the list to that size

the most Pythonic way to do the first bit is to catch the error (something you could also do with dicts if setdefault and defaultdict didn't exist). The whole thing looks like this:

```
results = []
for word in words:
    try:
        results[len(word)]
    except IndexError:
        # Grow the list so that the new highest index is 
        # len(word)
        new_length = len(word) + 1
        difference = len(results) - new_length
        results.extend([] for _ in range(difference))
    finally:
        results[len(word)].append(word)
```

Stay with dicts to avoid this kind of mess. lists are specifically optimised for the case that the exact numeric index of any element isn't meaningful outside of the list, which doesn't meet your use case. This type of code is *really common* when you have a mismatch between what your code needs to do and what the data structures you're using are good at, and it is worth learning as early as possible how to avoid it.

Comment: That's a great module - thank you for the detailed answer. We have some limitations about the sort of functions we're allowed to use but I really hope this is one of them. I'll definitely implement this for now.

However, in case I'm not allowed to use it, I have a preemptive follow up question. Let's say I have a listOfStuff length 2. Is there a way I can test if there exists listOfStuff[3] without throwing an error? If so, I would be able to generate more entries in the list from "largest recorded" to "current largest" value.

Comment: @Michi ehh.. kinda. See my updated answer for the full gory picture.

Comment: I definitely see how using the lists to do this is super clunky, but your answer taught me some more Python syntax (e.g. except, extend) and that's very good to know. Thank you.